# Python (pygame), spawning at random time

Tags: python, random, pygame

I am trying to make my first game in pygame and I run into some problems.
I don't know how to spawn my enemies at random times. When I do it in my while loop they show all at once.

Answer (score 1):

Every game loop add a chance to create an enemy. For example:

```
import random

# Main game loop
while True:
    if random.randrange(0, 100) < 1: # 1% chance every frame
        # Create a fly with specified properties
        Fly(random.randrange(xmin, xmax), random.randrange(ymin, ymax), width, height, img_src)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Could you tell me one more thing? I dont have idea how to avoid fire overlapping in Bugprojectile. Here is complite code: http://paste.ofcode.org/LKrkiHtYuiHbfViKeAituT

Comment: What do you mean by overlapping?

Comment: I did notice that you have all sprites being drawn as well as bug projectiles being drawn, although bug projectiles are a part of the main sprite group. This is probably causing multiple fire images to be placed.

Comment: I fixed it. Thank you very much for your help :)